# Elegant way to return from try...catch - Javascript

Tags: javascript, try-catch

Elegant way to return null. Don't want to return it twice.

**Option 1:**

```
function readSessionStorage(key) {
    try {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            return JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(key));
        }
        return null;
    } catch {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**Option 2:**

```
function readSessionStorage(key) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(key));
    } catch {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Option 3:**
If we pick this option, why should we do this?

```
function readSessionStorage(key) {
    try {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            return JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(key));
        }
    } catch {}
    return null;
}
```

---

**Why do I need to do this?**

I'm getting DOMException if I try to get `window.sessionStorage`, and hence I need to use `try...catch`.

```
function readSessionStorage(key) {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' || !window.sessionStorage) {
        return JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(key));
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

**Original Code:**

```
function readSessionStorage(key) {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        return JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(key));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: 2 looks fine. 3 looks odd, do you think there are some situations where the code wouldn't be running in a browser? (in which case calling `readSessionStorage` at all wouldn't make much sense IMO)

Comment: I'm quite confident that 2 should work, but wanted to be very safe with the original code (attached at the end)

Comment: What are you actually trying to catch

Comment: @Bergi, I was trying to `return null` for any other scenario than `typeof window !== 'undefined'`, but blocking cookies was giving me DOMException error, and I found no other way to handle it. So I tried try...catch, and it worked, but the problem was as you see in `Option 1`, I was returning null twice, and was thinking how I can just return it once. And that without breaking the anything in the original code (at the end of the question). I was not 100% sure that try...catch should take care of everything, maybe I'm just overcomplicating myself and 2 just works fine.

Comment: Ah, if you're not trying to catch JSON parsing errors I would've suggested to move the storage access into a separate part. But either way, option 2 is totally fine and straightforward.

Comment: Perfect, appreciate the response. Fan moment, I saw you 3-4 years ago when I just started answering on SO, and came across your profile and saw the way you responded and learned a lot from that. Thank you for inspiring.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's odd.  No response in seven months?  Well, I was looking for something like this myself, and couldn't find an eloquent solution.  I created my own.

---

**Edit**: upon further work, I found that the null safety operators *do* exist in JS!  Yay!  The function below is still quite helpful, perhaps more so now since one can use the safety operator to get to the precise value desired, then handle it correctly.

---

Consider using a function similar to this:

```
const defineCheck = (item, defaultVal = '') => { 
    try {
        return (item !== null && item !== undefined) ? item : defaultVal;
    } catch {
        return defaultVal;
    }
}
```

This might not exactly fit your needs, but you can make your function however you want.  This will keep the clutter out of your important business or UI logic, so you and others can focus on what is important.

Sample usage (if account is known to have an expected value):

```
tempForm.ExpirationDate = defineCheck(account.expirationDate);
tempForm.LicenseType = defineCheck(account.licenseType, 'Nada');
```

With null safety:

```
tempForm.ExpirationDate = defineCheck(account?.license?.expireDate);
tempForm.LicenseType = defineCheck(account?.license?.licenseType, 'Nada');
```

I hope you and others find this useful, or better yet, share a much better way to deal with this problem.  <s>I'd hoped the C# null safety check operator made its way to JS, but no luck (e.g., "account?.license?.licenseType ?? 'Nada'")</s>